# string.split with RegExp \s

Tags: javascript, regex

i try to split words in a String with string.split() and use regExp as separator, it also splits with s.

```
'what a mess'.split(RegExp('[\s]')); // -> ["what", "a", "me", "", ""]
```

how can i say that only the whitespace is a separator?
thanks you for the help

Comment: Get rid of the `[]`: try `'what a mess'.split(/\s+/)`

Comment: `'what a mess'.split(/\s+/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give a string to the `RegExp` constructor, any backslashes are interpreted as escaping something in the string itself, and they don't make it into the regex. You can either double escape your backslashes, or use a regex literal:

```js
console.log('what a mess'.split(RegExp('[\s]')));

console.log('what a mess'.split(RegExp('[\\s]')));
console.log('what a mess'.split(/[\s]/));
```

Comment: Why the DV? This seems perfectly cogent.